# SDL2 > PNG IMAGE > couldn't load the image

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

**SITUATION**

I want to load and use my image (which is .png) in my app. However when I try to load the image I get the following error

> Error at ./sources/texture.c:9: 'The texture is NULL'
>
> > Couldn't open pawn.png

**CODE**

*texture.c*

```
texture_t*
texture_load(renderer_t *renderer, const char *path) {
    texture_t *tex = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, path);

    if (tex == NULL)
        error_print(AT, "The texture is NULL");

    return tex;
}
```

*game.c*

```
game_t*
game_create() {
    ...
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    ...
    texture_load(renderer, "pawn.png")
    ...
}
```

**FOLDER STRUCTURE**

```
.
├── build
│   ├── app
│   └── pawn.png
├── headers
│   ...
│   ├── game.h
|   ...
│   ├── texture.h
│   ...
├── resources
│   └── pawn.png
└── sources
    ...
    ├── game.c
    ...
    ├── texture.c
    ...
```

**BONUS**

if You want to see the whole "image" of my project then You can click [here](https://gitlab.com/hr4nt/chess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a silly hypothesis, but are you sure the file is in the current application directory?

On a POSIX system you can check it with:

```
if (access("pawn.png", F_OK) == 0) {
    printf("File exists\n");
} else {
    printf("File doesn't exist\n");
}
```

If it prints `File doesn't exist`, then you need to specify a full path to the file.

Comment: I'm currently getting issues with F_OK, It says that F_OK is undeclared. NOTE: I'm running Manjaro

Comment: Yes, I do. Should I include some headers for it? Can't find something useful in internet sadly.

Comment: Now it works... It printed out "file doesn't exist", but how?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add "build/pawn.png"... now says that file exists. NOTE: app is also in build folder. BUT if application is in build folder doesn't that mean that it should've worked without include build into build/pawn.png

Comment: When you try to open `"pawn.png"` , it means it will try to open it from the current application directory which is a runtime application setting. Obviously, the file doesn't exist there. I'd suggest to specify a full path to the file.

Just for testing purposes, you can put the PNG file into the `/tmp` directory, and try to load `"/tmp/pawn.png"`. I'm sure it will work fine. This way we know the SDL library works fine and the PNG file is fine as well.

Comment: >BUT if application is in build folder doesn't that mean that it should've worked without include build

For example:

`cd /some/path; ./build/app`

The current application directory is `/some/path`, not `/some/path/build`. Hope this helps.

Comment: ***It printed out "file doesn't exist", but how?*** Because `c++` is exact. If you did not put a path with the file name, it looks only in the current working directory. No searching will occur.

Comment: @drescherjm 1) I'm doing it with C 2) if You were right then it should've found my image, because I can clearly see that it is there :D

Comment: I think the current working directory is different than you believe.

Comment: @drescherjm aaah now I get what You mean... because I'm running ./build/app, It thinks that my directory is '.' and not the './build'... good to know.

and it throws segmentation fault now.

Comment: ***it throws segementation fault now*** I expect that is a different bug.

Comment: @Hrant It's a different bug I believe. Try to recompile your app with debugging information turned on (`-ggdb` GCC switch) and run in `gdb`. See http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html

I'd also suggest to use some build system like cmake.